# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Java Issue

Tags: java

So I have been working on this problem for a while now. I keep getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` but I am unable to locate where the issue lies. If someone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it! Thanks!

```
public class Answer {   

    public static void main(String[] args){
        double[] y = {23, 11.1, 50.4};
        double[] x = {22.2, 46, 100.0};
        Answer answer = new Answer();
        answer.answer(y, x);
    }
    public static int answer(double[] y, double[] x) { 
        int result = 0;
        double percent_1, percent_2;
        double[] compareList_1 = new double[x.length];
        double[] compareList_2 = new double[y.length];

        // Calculate percent of first 2 x value array items with y
        // all y values. Store the results in a seperate list.
        for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            percent_1 = compare(y[i], x[0]);
            percent_2 = compare(y[i], x[1]);
            compareList_1[i] = percent_1;
            compareList_2[i] = percent_2;
        }
        // Compare those lists to find common number
        // There you have your answer.
        result = (int)compareLists(compareList_1, compareList_2);
        return result;
    }
    // Calculates percentage from x and y values
    public static double compare(double y, double x){
        double result = 1 - (y/x);
        return result;
    }
    // Finds common value in lists
    public static double compareLists(double[] list_1, double[] list_2){
        for(int i = 0; i < list_1.length + 1; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < list_2.length + 1; j++){
                if(list_1[i] == list_2[j]){
                    return list_1[i];
                }
            }
        }
        // Just cus this shouldn't ever return.
        return 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: check the error and give the line number

Comment: can u paste the stacktrace

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot print the line number due to the compiler I am using. If I knew the line number or stacktrace, I would have probably solved this by now. All I know is that the exception was thrown by the function Answer. Thanks

Comment: If you're convinced it's coming directly from the `answer` method, there are very limited places it could come from there. It's possible if (1) `x.length < 2`, or (2) `y.length < x.length`. You should be able to at least add `System.out` level debugging statements to clarify this.  That being said, it's difficult to help you if you can't provide info like a stack trace.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks for the help but It had nothing to do with the code, it was a logic error

Comment: @BillBentley just fyi, but if you have an exception, then by default you have a stacktrace. If you are unable to retrieve that stacktrace, then there is something wrong with the way you are handling exceptions. Unless you are mangling it through some kind of an obfuscator. Example - capture all and just printing the message is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problerm is in

```
for(int i = 0; i < list_1.length + 1; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < list_2.length + 1; j++){
```

`i < list_1.length + 1` or `j < list_2.length + 1` change it to

```
 for(int i = 0; i < list_1.length; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < list_2.length ; j++){
```

remove `+1` from each condition.For `j < list_2.length + 1` the  `list_2.length` will give you length of array ie `lastIndex +1` and you are adding another `+1` in it causing loop condition to be  `j<lastIndex +1` giving you index error on the last iteration of loop in the line `if(list_1[i] == list_2[j]){` for `list_2[j]`

Also in answer method you declare array by

```
double[] compareList_1 = new double[x.length];
double[] compareList_2 = new double[y.length];
```

and in the loop you are iterating upto `x.length` if `x.length` is greater than  `y.length` the you can get the Index error in `compareList_2[i] = percent_2;`(inside the loop) because its length is `y.length`.

Comment: @BillBentley can you post the complete stacktrace and point to line where the error is(it would be given in the error)

Answer (score 1):

In your iteration (compareLists), you should use 'length' (not length + 1)

```
for(int i = 0; i < list_1.length; i++)
   for(int j = 0; j < list_2.length; i++)
```

Comment: I just copied your code and fixed it, it really does work... did you change both places (i and j)?

Comment: bud - you are incrementing `i` in both for loops. You might want to correct that.